# What Java code is better?

Tags: java

I have a

```
List<String>list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to add some Strings.

My code is like this

```
final int howMany = 13;
list.add(howMany+"");
```

Just like int is not Serializable i pass it to a String I know this String is not pooled mean that is creating a Object everytime right because is generated a runtime?

But in my code the code reviewer change it to.

```
String.valueOf(howMany);
```

I just checked the code and is something like

```
return Integer.toString(i);
```

Which ends in.

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

Which is creating a `new String()` also.

Now my question is which is code is better for performance, readable better code?

`howMany + ""` vs `String.valueOf(howMany)`

I have made a simple Benchmarking a `String.valueOf()` is slower I think..

```
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<99900000;i++){
        //final String string = i+"";//2637ms..
        final String string = String.valueOf(i);//3600ms..
    }
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endTime-startTime+"ms..");
```

`String.valueOf()` is 50% slower than the `i + ""`.

Using J.D.K 1.8.0_121

Comment: the bigger question is....why does a list contain vars of essentially different types?

Comment: Are you asking what's *better* between `howMany + ""` and `String.valueOf(howMany)`?

Comment: Better? *To store Strings,int,Doubles and so on*? Store **one** type. `List<Integer>` for example. If you need to store multiple things, create a custom class so you store **one** type. `List<MyClass>` is **better** in that case.

Comment: No matter which you choose, the JIT compiler will optimize your choice.

Answer (score 2):

`String.valueOf()` is better for the following reasons:

1. other people know instantly what you've done because you've done it in the same way other people do it.
2. You're creating an extra string the other code is not, the empty string: `""` which needs to be created then (uselessly) concatenated to Java's conversion of your int to a String.
3. Your code also goes through the more or less same process as the other code, just behind the scenes- Java has basically one algorithm for changing ints to Integers to String representations of Integers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one first wonders why you can't use a boxed integer, i.e. Integer. After all, you already have objects rather than primitive types in that list... that's what I would try and write. Also, as @MitchWheat suggests - make sure you actually *need* a list of arbitrary Serializable's; it's often  better if you can constrain the element types in your lists.

Between the two options, your reviewer's suggestion is preferable:

- It says exactly what you mean to achieve.
- It doesn't introduce an artifact to people reading the code.
- It seems (to me, subjectively) to be more likely to get compiled by the VM if called multiple times.
- Your code creates *two* strings, at least as its written and regardless of compiler/VM optimizations, while the valueOf() should only create one. **edit:** ... but I concede that's not a guarantee of better performance.

Finally, about your benchmark result - what can I see, Java is weird. I would recommend readability over measured performance for anything that's not the performance-critical section; and for that one - Java is a questionable choice anyway.

Comment: ...and misses the real problem entirely!

Comment: @MitchWheat: It is not inconceivable that a list would contain arbitrary serializable values. I mean, I could probably think up some use case.

Comment: yes so can I, but the other 99.99% of the time.....

Comment: @MitchWheat: Edited based on your comment. I'm not sure it's a 99.99% though.

Comment: Your code creates two strings, at least as its written and regardless of compiler/VM optimizations, while the valueOf() should only create one. in my simple benchmarking the String.valueOf is slower.

Comment: @chiperortiz: Describe exactly how you benchmarked, please.

Comment: is in the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf(howMany)` is much more readable and that's what matters in my opinion.
What's more, it does the same, so in terms of efficiency it's almost identical, and I think it's always better to be readable.